# Show references in Author, Year, Title, Source, (other data) With Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I would like to use Bibtex to write references and citations for work for my University.

I have got the LaTeX and BibTex combination down perfectly for referances bar one thing.

For the reference style, my University requires the following:

> Surname, F(irstname).(YEAR) *Title of referenced piece.* Further data, eg, web URL, Place of publication, Publisher, Pages of article etc etc

For example, a reference must look like this:

> Bloggs, J.(1940) *The life of Pi*. London:A Publisher

Using Bibtex, nattex with LaTeX i have achieved something mostly like this:

> Bloggs, J. *The Life of Pi*. London: A Publisher. 2005

but I can't get the year to display after the author, it always displays right at the end of the referance.

How can I get the year to display after after the author in brackets?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into using the `makebst` utility -- part of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package -- to create your own customized bibliography style file? Placing the publication year, in parentheses, immediately after author block should be easily achievable if you follow the prompts of the `makebst` utility.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue by using:

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

References now display exactly how I need them too.

Comment: You may want to inform your university that the `apalike` bibliography style meets its formatting requirements for bibliographies. Having this piece of information handy will save future students a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll try and find the right person to speak to and get the comment added to the referencing guide somewhere. It certainly would have saved me some time.